# Angular/Spring MVC: how to fix the error "Required request body is missing"

Tags: angular, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having a problem deleting a product from the db in the frontend (angular).
I'm having this error:

*Required request body is missing: public boolean prodcust.controller.DeleteController.deleteProduct(java.lang.String,prodcust.model.Product)]*

I tested the Delete API in Postman and it works fine, the problem I'm only having in Angular when I click the Delete button.

**CONTROLLER**:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete-product/{codeproduct}",method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public boolean deleteProduct(@PathVariable("codeproduct") String codeproduct, @RequestBody Product product) {
    product.setCodeproduct(codeproduct);
    return productDao.deleteProduct(product);
}
```

**DAO**:

```java
public boolean deleteProduct(Product product) {
    boolean status=false;
    try {
        jdbcTemplate.update("delete from buys where codeproduct=?", product.getCodeproduct());
        status=true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
}
```

Angular: **service.ts**

```js
return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/delete-product/${codeproduct}`, { responseType: 'text' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `@RequestBody Product product` try to send some json object or  empty json `{}` from angular.

Use as below.

```
http.request('delete',. , `${this.baseUrl}/delete-product/${codeproduct}`, body: { } });
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do this? i am a beginner in angular

Comment: We are send empty body

Comment: thanks, now it works. The only thing, to be more correct, is to write: {body: {}}

Answer (score 1):

Your backend API is expecting a request body of type `Product`. But angular call with `http.delete` is not passing it which is causing the error.

Instead you can use `http.request` instead with the json as body:

```
return this.http.request('delete', `${this.baseUrl}/delete-product/${codeproduct}`, {body: prodObj});
```

Comment: i tried to edit but it still keeps giving me that problem. In addition to modifying service.ts, do I also need to modify something else?
I'm a beginner

Comment: Not required, can you confirm if you are passing the `prodObj` with a value assigned to it?

Comment: yes I am passing the object with the appropriate codeproduct. I would like to understand if I have to modify other code in angular besides the service.ts